# Data passed between two forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a project that include two forms. I must pass the `textbox1` data in `form2` to variable string `m` defined in `form1`. My code is written below but variable string `m` is constant.

Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm1 = new Form1();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.ModifyTextBoxValue = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string m = "12";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ModifyTextBoxValue
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set {  m = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass reference of Form1 to Form2 - and in Form1 expose properties that you want to share between them.

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple I would try this example:

Form2 Class

```
private string welcomeToStackOverflow;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     textBox1.Text = welcomeToStackOverflow;
     Form1 frm = new Form1(welcomeToStackOverflow);

}
```

Form1 Class

```
private string welcome;
public Form1(string wel)
{
    this.welcome = wel;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `form2` code and get the reference of `form1` (as **Yanshof** said):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form2(Form refForm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //frm1 = new Form1();    //remove this line
        frm1 = refForm1;    //assign reference of "form1" to "frm1"
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.ModifyTextBoxValue = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Now you need to pass the reference as well. When you call `form2`, call like this:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);    //here "this" is the reference of "Form1"
```